# Update button not getting the query

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates

thanks for your time:
I've got a model that is linked to the user and the only one that can update him its his creator. untill that works fine. just the creator user can open the url update although i'm not beeing able to pass a button on the main template of the model with redirect to that update url.

i'd like to know if there is a way to that button apear just to his user (if not ok, to get in just open to the matching queryset user).

Or just why this button ain't working: i should get the url eg:services/parceiro/update/2 i'm beeing able to open this url if i'm the creator user but when i try to set it in a button i get this error:

Reverse for 'update_parceiro2' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['services/parceiro/update/(?P[0-9]+)$']

parceiros.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{parc.nome}} - {{parc.user}} - {{parc.responsavel}}</h1>


    <form action="{% url 'update_parceiro2' Parceiros.id %}">
        <button type="submit"><i class="material-icons">sync</i></button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
def parceirosview(request, pk=None):
    parc = get_object_or_404(Parceiros, id=pk)
    context = {'parc': parc}
    return render(request, 'parceiro.html', context)

    def get_queryset(self):
     return super().get_queryset().filter(parceiro__user=self.request.user)

class ParceiroUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Parceiros
    template_name = 'parceiroform.html'
    fields = ['nome', 'endereco', 'responsavel', 'tel']

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home_view, name='home2'),
    path('parceiro/', views.parceirosview, name='parceiro2'),
    path('parceiro/detail/<int:pk>', views.parceirosview, name='parceiro_detail2'),
    path('addparceiro/', views.parceiros_create, name='add_parceiro2'),
    path('parceiro/detail2/<int:pk>', ParceirosView.as_view(), name='parceiro_detail22'),
    path('parceiro/update/<int:pk>', ParceiroUpdate.as_view(), name='update_parceiro2')
]
```

models.py:

```
get_user_model = User

class Parceiros (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    endereco = models.TextField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    responsavel = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tel = PhoneField(max_length=12)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    ativo = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(Parceiros, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user, self.nome)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('parceiro_detail2', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: This `{% url 'update_parceiro2' Parceiros.id %}` should probably be `{% url 'update_parceiro2' parc.id %}`

Comment: kkkkk tham right sir thank you i 'v not notice that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your template to display content for user based on his id

```
{% if request.user.id == 1 %}
<form action="{% url 'update_parceiro2' Parceiros.id %}">
    <button type="submit"><i class="material-icons">sync</i></button>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Please explain more.

Comment: thank you sir, it worked but would be like:
```
{% if request.user == parc.user  %}    
    <form action="{% url 'update_parceiro2' parc.id %}">
        <button type="submit"><i class="material-icons">sync</i></button>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```